# Is this the right place to ask about UK Government policy on renaming "ministries" to "departments"?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask the following.

> **Why has the UK Government moved away from "Ministry of..." names?**
>
> Traditionally, UK Government departments were named "Ministry of [blar]". For example,
>
> - Ministry of Transport
> - Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food
> - Ministry of Education
>
> In recent years, many of these have been retired in favour of "Department for [blar]". For example,
>
> - Ministry of Transport → Department for Transport
> - Ministry of Agriculture, Fisheries and Food → Department for Environment, Food and Rural Affairs
> - Ministry of Education → Department for Education
>
> Why is Britain getting rid of its "Ministries" and replacing them with "Departments"?

Is this the right place to ask this?

Comment: Asked on [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/69047/39976) as suggested.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I think this is a perfectly valid question for Politics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -7):

I disagree with [Philipp](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6004/27084) on this one, and I think this would be off topic because

> Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, how specific individuals would behave in hypothetical situations or predictions for future events are off-topic, because answers would be based on **speculation** and their correctness **could not be verified with sources available to the public.**

(That’s one of our custom close reasons)

So I would vote to close it on the main site.

Comment: As these are government departments rather than "specific individuals" then is this section still relevant?

Comment: @JamesGeddes It still couldn’t be verified with sources available to the public, so the close reason still applies. Also, governments are run by individuals.

Comment: When a government department gets renamed, then it would really surprise me when the press release announcing the change doesn't mention any reason whatsoever.